# Assign python dictionary keys to different matrices

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

I am trying to use a dictionary to assign different keys to different matrices in python 2.7.

***EDIT -- SORRY FOR LACK OF INFO PREVIOUSLY***

Here is a full, working example of my code:

```
import random
matrices_dict = {}

matrix = [[1,1],
        [1,1],]

def checker(key_number):
    for x in range(0, 2):
        for y in range(0, 2):
            matrix[x][y] = random.randint(0, 9)

    matrices_dict[key_number] = matrix
    print matrices_dict

checker(0)
checker(1)
```

... then I see that the resulting dictionary does NOT store the two different matrices that were generated. Instead it has made BOTH dictionary keys 1 and 2 correspond to the second matrix.

In other words it's over-writing the first key's pairing. That's odd to me because I'm pretty clearly asking it to just write the new matrix to the new key.

Any advice on how to get it to not overwrite the first key/matrix pairing?

***HERE'S WHAT SOLVED IT***

```
import random
matrices_dict = {}

def checker(key_number):
     matrix = [[1,1],
              [1,1],]
    for x in range(0, 2):
        for y in range(0, 2):
            matrix[x][y] = random.randint(0, 9)

    matrices_dict[key_number] = matrix
    print matrices_dict

checker(0)
checker(1)
```

... I am not clear WHY the second one works and the first one doesn't. In the first one, why does it need a new matrix each time the definition is called?... why doesn't over-write the previously-created random one work?

And regardless, why should any of those details of the matrix creation impact whether the *dictionary* overwrites its previous key pairings or not?

Would be interested to know out of curiosity!

Comment: Do these reference to the *same* object? How is the matrix generated? Looks to me you simply *alter* the matrix instead of constructing a new one.

Comment: No I checked it ..it works fine. I gave `matrix=[1,2,3]` as a sample. Maybe something wrong with generated matrix? or some other problem?

Comment: obviously you're using global values inside the function, print them to see what happen when you call `checker(X)`

Comment: If both *reference* the same object. Then it means both times *same matrix* was generated.

Comment: You give too few details for us to help much. Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks all, and sorry for the lack of clarity. I have edited my question to provide complete, verifiable examples. I also solved the problem for my needs -- but I don't understand why it works that way, so if any of you know it'd be interesting to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the idea is to generate a new object referenced by (called) matrix, and save a reference (dict key) to this new object when the function is called. For example:

```
 import numpy as np
 matrices_dict = {}

 def checker(key_number):
      # here we create a new object and add a reference 
      # (key in this case) to this new object to the dict.
      # Note that each time this func is called, this line is executed
      # and thus a new object is created
      matrix = np.random.rand(1,2)
      matrices_dict[key_number] = matrix

 checker(1)
 checker(2)

 print(matrices_dict)
```

which produces something like:
`{1: array([[ 0.33570685,  0.66721728]]), 2: array([[ 0.57074373,  0.62535056]])}`

And we get two different matrices, this seems exactly what you want right?

But what goes wrong in the next piece of code is the following. A single object is created and each time the function is called a new reference to this single object is added to the dict.

```
 import numpy as np
 matrices_dict = {}
 # here we create a single object
 # Note that this line gets executed only once, so there is really 
 # just a single object that can be changed and referenced to.
 matrix = np.random.rand(1,2)     

 def checker(key_number):
      # add a new reference (key in this case) to the single object 
      # we created above to the dict
      matrices_dict[key_number] = matrix

 checker(1)
 checker(2)

 print(matrices_dict)
```

Then we get the wrong behaviour as you describe it:
`{1: array([[ 0.86548754,  0.92694858]]), 2: array([[ 0.86548754,  0.92694858]])}`

The key is to understand references and objects. When you created a list you created an object which was initially referenced by 'matrix'. Then when the function got called a new reference was created, to the same object!, in the form of a dictionary key. So when you used a dictionary key, or 'matrix', you ended up accessing and changing the same object.

Comment: Thanks for this. My problem was similar but a little less obvious, as I was altering the matrix within the definition, so it seemed pretty clear to me that I was not calling the same matrix.

I've edited my comment above with the exact details and what ended up working, but I'm still not fully sure why it works that way, so if you have thoughts on that, that'd be interesting.

Comment: It becomes clear when you fully understand how references and objects work, so I advise you to look up some info about that. That info will help you in any programming language you might encounter. I edit my answer in the hope that that will clarify it for you.